# Xcode: programmatically make Xcode show a particular file/line-number?

Tags: xcode, applescript, xcode6

Is there a way to programmatically make Xcode (6+) show a particular file/line-number in an open project/workspace? E.g. a plugin or extant Applescript. Particularly, I'd like to do this from another app.

Related: ["Xcode: programmatically determine what's open"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25976327)

Answer (score 0):

Check out the man page for `xed`.

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/xed.1.html